# Why $E[X_iX_j] = P(X_i=1, X_j=1)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

This is a probability problem.

At a party, n people put their hats and they handed in their own hats into a box.

After enjoying party, they picked up one of them.

\begin{align}
X_iX_j&=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \mbox{if the ith and jth party goers both select their own hats.}\\
0 & otherwise.
\end{array} \right.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
E[X_iX_j]&=P\{X_i=1, X_j=1\}\\
&=P(X_i=1)P(X_j=1|X_i=1)\\
&=\frac1n \frac1{n-1}
\end{align}

In this process, I don't understand where and how $E[X_iX_j]=P\{X_i=1, X_j=1\}$ come into existence. Please give me some hints or explanation? thank you!

Comment: I think confusion may arise because $X_i, X_j$ are not explicitly defined. Writing $P\{X_i=1,X_j=1\}$ is just a convenient way of saying $P\{\text{both $i,j$ pick their own hats}\}$. You could also write this as $P\{X_i=2,X_j=1/2\}$, for instance, and in that case you define $X_i, X_j$ in a slightly different way, but both refers to the same event.

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion. I should have added $E(X_i)=/frac1n$ for $i=1,2,...,n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_i,X_j$ take values in $\{0,1\}$, the product $X_iX_j$ is equal to $1$ if $X_i=X_j=1$, and 0 if at least one of the two is $0$.

So $$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[ X_iX_j ] &= 1\cdot \mathbb{P}\{X_i=1\text{ and }X_j=1\}+ 0\cdot \mathbb{P}\{X_i=0\text{ or }X_j=0\} \\&= \mathbb{P}\{X_i=1\text{ and }X_j=1\}\end{align}$$
by definition of the expectation as $\mathbb{E}[Z]=\sum_{a} a \mathbb{P}\{Z=a\}$ (for $Z$ being a discrete random variable).

Comment: The above, of course, relies on the (implicit in your question) definition of $X_i$ being the indicator event of "party goer $i$ chooses her own hat.". That is, $$X_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if  party goer } i \text{ chooses her own hat}\\0 &\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm impressed nice answer. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!